# MariaDB, MySQL - aggregated count in group

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Suppose there is a table:

| first | second | third |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |

And by query:

```
SELECT first, count(*) AS cnt
FROM table
GROUP BY first
```

We get result:

| first | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 |

How to calculate count of another column (columns) inside group?
Expected result:

| first | cnt | aggregated_count_by_second | aggregated_count_by_third |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | {1: 3, 2: 1} | {1: 2, 2: 2} |
| 2 | 1 | {3: 1} | {1: 1} |

DB version: 10.3.39-MariaDB-0+deb10u1

Comment: The task can be easily solved on MariaDB 10.5+: https://dbfiddle.uk/deWSlyvq Maybe it's a time to upgrade?

Comment: "Easily solved"??  The point is that you cannot do it in a single grouping; instead you need to do separate steps, then put the pieces together.